# SQL Subquery error near )

Tags: sql

My subquery gives an error: `Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 17 Incorrect syntax near ')'.`

```
SELECT SalesArea, Branch, Volume
from
(select 
br.SalesArea as SalesArea
,br.Branch as Branch
, sum(a.Volume) as Volume
FROM dbo.vDetail a with (nolock) 
LEFT JOIN
dbo.vBranch AS br WITH (nolock) 
ON a.Branch = br.Branch
group by a.Volume, br.SalesArea, br.Branch)
```

Comment: you probably need to give the subquery an alias. ) qry.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are missing alias for subquery try out this.

```
SELECT SalesArea, Branch, Volume
from
(select 
br.SalesArea as SalesArea
,br.Branch as Branch
, sum(a.Volume) as Volume
FROM dbo.vDetail a with (nolock) 
LEFT JOIN
dbo.vBranch AS br WITH (nolock) 
ON a.Branch = br.Branch
group by a.Volume, br.SalesArea, br.Branch) as x
```

Answer (score 9):

Every select from subquery needs an alias. Just add an "X" in the end that will become the name of the table

NOT OK:

```
select * from (
   select * from your_table
)
```

OK:

```
select * from (
   select * from your_table
) X
```

Answer (score 1):

You need alias name for a derived table

```
SELECT SalesArea, Branch, Volume 
from 
(select  
br.SalesArea as SalesArea 
,br.Branch as Branch 
, sum(a.Volume) as Volume 
FROM dbo.vDetail a with (nolock)  
LEFT JOIN 
dbo.vBranch AS br WITH (nolock)  
ON a.Branch = br.Branch 
group by a.Volume, br.SalesArea, br.Branch) as T
```